# Send Google Form data through email with Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I'm trying to set up a google spreadsheet to send an email when certain values are changed to yes. So far, I've got it where it's working, except the variables task and program are "undefined."

Secondly, I only want it to send an email if no is changed to yes. So say E2 is already "yes" but E3 is no. Someone goes in and changes E3 to yes...I just want to email the information in column 3 not 2.

Lastly, how do I get it check everything in column E for a "yes:...so E2 through E50? Right now, it's only checking if E4.. I want to set it to check the whole column.

I'm a novice with javascript and seem to be stuck. Thanks.

```
  function readCell() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses");  
    var value = sheet.getRange("G4").getValue();
    var task = sheet.getRange("E4").getValue();
    var program = sheet.getRange("C4").getValue();
    if(value="Yes") sendEmail(value);
    if(value="Yes") sendEmail(task);
    if(value="Yes") sendEmail(program);
    };


    function sendEmail(value, task, program) {
    var email = "test@gmail.com";
    var subject = "Jacob has completed a task.";
    var body = "This is an automated generated email, Jacob Workman has completed  for " + task + "for" + program;

    var oauthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService("google");
    oauthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken");
    oauthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?scope=https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/");
    oauthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken");
    oauthConfig.setConsumerKey("anonymous");
    oauthConfig.setConsumerSecret("anonymous");
    MailApp.sendEmail(email,subject,body); 

    };
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your `sendEmail()` function has 3 arguments, but when your using it your only passing in one value as the `value` variable. Try:

```
if(value="Yes") {
    sendEmail(value, task, program);
}
```

Instead of each line separately

Answer (score 1):

*EDIT* As Akum points out, you also have the parameter's wrong.

You are accidentally doing an assignment where you mean to be doing a compare.

```
if(value === "Yes") sendEmail(value, task, program);
```

Though it could be better written as:

```
if(value === "Yes") {
  sendEmail(value, task, program);
}
```

BTW: There is great tool called [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/) that helps find common issues like `=` and `===`